# Is there a dataset that provides shopping conversations?

Tags: dataset, chatbot, nlp

I want to create a chatbot application, but I need conversational data about users asking for sales or orders on e-commerce.

Does anyone provide a dataset like this? All datasets I have found provided just general conversation not related to a shopping domain.

Comment: It would be more relevant to ask questions about datasets there: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LiamRoels the url you provided cannot be accessed

Comment: @devFaris sorry I copied the wrong link... I meant this one: https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/72ivfo/im_looking_for_a_retail_dataset_dummy_or/